# What stats test to use for a time to event analysis for tumor formation in mice in R

Tags: r, time-series, statistical-significance, survival

I am working on a project where we are injecting mice with a virus to induce gene deletions and cause tumor formation.  We developed a new gene deletion method and want to see if it causes tumors to grow faster than the standard method.  Would a KM curve be ideal for this? And how can we determine if the difference in time to formation is significant.  I am new to stats and data analytics.

*edit for more details*
We are injecting mice with two different Ad-Cre recombinase solutions (Injection A (control) and Injection B (test)) to induce genetic deletions to grow tumors.  We check the mice once a week for palpable tumor, and once one is felt, we measured with a caliper until the tumor had a volume of 1cm^3.  In terms of what data was collected: we have the date of injection, date of when the tumor was at the threshold volume (unfortunately, serial measurements were not collected to determine a rate of growth or anything of the sort), and when the mice expired (either naturally due to the tumor or sacrificed).

We have 35 mice in each group, our primary variable of interest was a binary: did more tumors grow with Injection A (12/35) or Injection B (31/35). But, based on a macroscopic view data collected we thought an interesting secondary outcome to evaluate time to tumor formation since the test injection group grew tumors in 2-4 weeks, versus the control groups growth in 250 days.  Obviously, at first glance there is an obvious signal there.

I was unsure if we could just perform a simple unpaired t-test to see if the average time to tumor formation has a significant difference, but I thought that would be too rudimentary, thus my question about KM curves.

Thanks for the helpful tips and advice, much appreciated!

We are hypothesizing that this new ad-cre system develops more tumors in a mouse colony, and does so quicker and in the desired location (arm, leg, body, etc).

We initially ran a two sample Z test, to determine the the difference in proportion of tumor was significant, and are now looking at if the time to tumor growth is significant.

Comment: Welcome to cv! A KM curve is good for time-to-event data (time until tumor formation). Do you also monitor tumor growth over time? Your question is quite vague and therefore hard to answer. If you already have data, then it would be good to describe what the data look like (measured variables, and how many data you have). It would also be good if you could give some more precise questions: what are your hypotheses (e.g. tumor diameter increases less fast in mutant mice, or the like).

Comment: If tumor growth is measured and has more than two numeric values, time to event analysis will lose tremendous power as opposed to a longitudinal analysis respecting the data generating mechanism.

Comment: Philyswiss, I can see your question is closed. This does not mean that it is lost;if you edit it and improve it, providing more details, it will be reconsidered. As you can see from @FrankHarrell 's comment, there are some experts here that can give you hints how to get modt information out of your valuable data.

Comment: @Ute, many thanks for the comments and help.  I have made edits to add more details to my original question, and I hope they give more context.

Comment: @FrankHarrell. thanks for the advice. I believe we only have two time points - date of injection and date of tumor formation meeting the threshold criteria.  I am unsure whether we can count date of death as we performed euthanasia on the mice to perform histology on the samples, and I am unsure if that is a form of censoring that would misrepresent any analysis

Comment: Hi Philyswiss, that is an extensive edit :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So death is not an outcome in this case and it may be OK to ignore it.  The use of a tumor size threshold in this design is questionable.  But at any rate this is a classic longitudinal continuous response setup with Y(t) = tumor size at time t and the correlation pattern will likely be something like AR(1) so that generalized least squares is a good candidate procedure, or a Markov process.  This would assume MAR (missing at random) which here translates to assuming that the probability of dropout (removal from study; sacrifice) depends on already-measured tumor sizes and not on a non-measured tumor size.

For a detailed case study using GLS and Markov methods (the latter using a semiparametric model so as to not assume a distribution for Y) see [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long.html).

From the longitudinal model you can draw inferences about differences in trajectories of tumor size, the size at a fixed time, and a variety of other estimands.  With a little more trouble you can use the continuous trajectory estimates to estimate time until tumor size exceeds a threshold.

Comment: Thanks.  Will this work even though the experiment treated the Y(t) as a binary? Tumor size was not continuously measured and/or recorded by the research personnel.  Once a tumor reached the threshold volume of 1 cubic cm, the date was recorded and the mouse was sacrificed for histological study a few days/weeks later. In essence, the Y(t) for all data points is 1 cm^3 for this experiment, but the mice developed the same size tumors at varying times.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: With a little bit of luck you'll still have MAR.  Y(t) is tumor size and is continuous because you'll have real measurements < 1cc.  Y(t) is truncated at 1cc and you might consider 1cc to be an absorbing state in a Markov ordinal semiparametric model (see final chapter of https://hbiostat.org/rmsc) if you are certain the tumor would not shrink below 1cc had the animal not been sacrificed.  It does not make sense if "same tumor size" also applies to 1cc as this would imply that 1cc did not always trigger a sacrifice.